# Stored Procedure to Validate Input Data before insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure to validate data before inserted into a table.

I have a CHANGES table that a user will be inserting values into (basically if there is wrong data in certain tables/columns in our system, this user will send us the correct data to update certain columns).  Before the data can be inserted into this CHANGES table, I would like to validate the input data against a LOOKUP table.  This lookup table essentially shows what is the accepted data type, length of column etc before insert.

Here is the lookup table:

| ID | TABLENAME | COLUMNAME | ACCEPTEDDATATYPE | ACCEPTEDLENGTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EMPLOYEE | AGE | INT |  |
| 2 | EMPLOYEE | MIDDLENAME | VARCHAR | 50 |
| 3 | DEPARTMENT | BLDG | VARCHAR | 10 |

Basically ID is the unique identifier, so if a user is inserting an ID of 1, we know they are trying to insert data for the employee table and making a correction to the AGE column, and in this case we only want to accept an int value.

Here is the structure of the CHANGES table:

| ID | PKFROMTABLE | NEWVALUE | USERNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234 | 39 | sk |
| 1 | 345 | john | jf |
| 2 | 455 | BIOL | jf |

I would like to wrap this in a stored procedure:  This is what I have so far

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CleanupData]
    (
    
    @ID int,
    @uniqueid VARCHAR(40),
    @value VARCHAR(50)


    )
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION AddLoopback
DECLARE @columnlength int;
DECLARE @columndatatype varchar(30);
set @columnlength=(select acceptedlength from lookup where ID=@ID)
set @columndatatype=(select accepteddatatype from lookup where ID=@ID)

    IF len(@value) <= @columnlength
    
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [CHANGES] (ID, pkfromtable,newvalue,USERNAME) VALUES (@ID, @uniqueid, @value,SUSER_SNAME())
    PRINT 'New Record Inserted'
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION AddLoopback
      PRINT 'id is not acceptable'
    END
GO
```

How would I add validation for the datatype?  And how would I make sure all validation passes before the insert?  If any validation would fail per record, I do not want that record inserted into the CHANGES tables.

Comment: FYI the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: Out of interest, why are you not just using a normalised design? Then you can just have a column called `Age` with the datatype `int` (though storing age is actually a poor idea unto itself), a column called `MIDDLENAME` defined as a `varchar(50)`, etc.

Comment: A single SQL statement is atomic. It either succeeds completely or fails. There is no need to start a transaction here at all. You should throw an error if it is not acceptable - do not PRINT as an alternative.

Comment: So Age is defined as int - that means you accept any integer? Like 0 or -4521 or 2,147,483,647?

Comment: @Larnu - Thanks for letting me know about naming with sp_.  I did not know that at all.  Also about the normlized design.  I will be taking the data that is inserted into the CHANGES table and actually applying it to the actual NORMALIZED tables after it is reviewed that the change is actually acceptable.  It was hard to explain what.  It's really just a holding table that documents possible changes needed to data already stored in "real tables"

Comment: Regarding normalized design. This is important but does not solve an underlying issue. If an insert query fails due to incorrect data ( string too long, etc. ) an Identity value is consumed anyway. Validation of all data before attempting an insert eliminates the gaps in identity values. The stored procedure is wise strategy if there isn't a code layer between the user input and the database to handle the validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can just check each datatype, do something like this

```
DECLARE @result BIT = 0;
IF @columndatatype = 'INT'
    SET @result = IIF(TRY_CAST(@value AS INT) IS NULL, 0, 1)
ELSE IF @columndatatype = 'BIGINT'
    SET @result = IIF(TRY_CAST(@value AS BIGINT) IS NULL, 0, 1)
ELSE IF @columndatatype = 'VARCHAR'
    SET @result = IIF(len(@value) <= @columnlength, 0, 1)
SELECT
    @result
```

If the cast fails, the result of the cast is null, and you set you @result to 0.

When you've finsihed your check you know if it is the correct format.

You could of course do this in a dynamic way, using sp_executesql as well.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I will try it out and see how it goes.  It is the help I was looking for to get started to validate the datatype of a particular column.